# Spotlight not working in Final Render (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

Having a bit of trouble with the spotlight when it comes between the preview render and the final render. In the preview render, everything is what I'd like the final render to be. I have a spotlight shining onto a platform in a cave, this is in the render preview.

[image]

However when I hit the render button on cycles, the result is a whole lot darker, as below.

[image]

I made sure the spotlight is close to the mesh, reset the transform and scale, adjusted the brightness and yet I still get this same result. Is there anything else I need to check or click in the light or render settings? Here are what I've set my lights and render too.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hello, have you checked in the Outliner if the light is enabled for render?

Comment: Where is that button located in Blender? Thanks!

Comment: In the Outliner, make sure that the camera icon is enabled for your light: https://zupimages.net/up/22/45/e7ef.jpg

Comment: Theres no camera icon next to the light, just an eyeball, is there any other way to see the icon?

Comment: Ah found it, yeah it appears the render camera is on for the spotlight

Comment: mmh that's weird, could you please share your file (at least a part of it)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140589/discussion-between-moonboots-and-gemma).